# How to handle kafka leader failover with two nodes for a topic with 2 partitions and 2 replicas?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, failover

I'm playing with kafka in a multi node environment to test how failover works.
Actually, i have 2 VMs with 1 kafka node inside each VM, and only 1 zookeeper inside one of the two VMs. I know that there is not an optimal production configuration, but it's just to train myself and understand things better.

Here is my configuration :
VM1 ip : 192.168.64.2 (With only one broker with broker.id=2)
VM2 ip : 192.168.64.3 (With zookeeper running here and broker with broker.id=1)

I start kafka through podman (this is not a problem with podman, everything is well configured)

On VM1 :

```
podman run -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=192.168.64.3:2181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://192.168.64.2:29092 -e KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2 -e KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT_HOST -e UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=true --pod zookeeper-kafka confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
```

On VM2 :

```
podman run -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:2181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://192.168.64.3:29092 -e KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2 -e KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT_HOST -e UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=true  --pod zookeeper-kafka confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
```

Now i create a topic "orders" :

```
./kafktopics --create --bootstrap-server 192.168.64.2:29092,192.168.64.3:29092 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic orders
```

Then i create a producer :

```
./kafkconsole-producer --broker-list 192.168.64.2:29092,192.168.64.3:29092 --topic orders
```

And a consumer :

````
./kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 192.168.64.2:29092,192.168.64.3:29092 --topic orders```
````

Here is what i am try to do :

1. Start Zookeeper, the 2 kafka nodes, create the "order" topic, the producer and the consumer (OK, everything works well)
2. Send message in my producer and check the consumer receive it (OK)
3. Kill the kafka node on VM2 (OK)
4. Send again a message in my producer and check the consumer receive it (OK, the broker on VM1 can distribute the message)
5. Restart the killed kafka node on VM2 (OK. After that i can see that the 2 partitions have VM1 as the leader)
6. Send again a message in my producer and check the consumer receive id (OK)
7. Kill the kafka node on VM1, which is the leader of the 2 partitions now (OK)
8. Send again a message in my producer and check the consumer receive it (OK, the broker on VM2 can distribute the message)
9. Restart the killed kafka node on VM1 (OK. After that i can see that the 2 partitions have VM2 as the leader)
10. Send again a message in my producer and check the consumer receive it (OK)
11. Kill again the kafka node on VM2 (OK)
12. Send again a message in my producer and check the consumer receive it (NOT OK):
    Here, the producer can't send the message, and my consumer never receive the message !
    After a few period, i get an error in my producer :

```
ERROR Error when sending message to topic orders with key: null, value: 9 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for orders-0:120000 ms has passed since batch creation
```

I really don't understand what is happening here ? It works well at the beginning, but after start/stop/start broker, it start to fail ! I need to precise that i never kill the 2 broker at the same time.

Could you please explain me what i am missing here ?

Thank you all :)

---

EDIT

To complete comments below:

@OneCricketeer, I put the answer of your comment here.

At startup, when all it's fine:

```
Topic: orders   TopicId: I3hMNln9TpSuo76xHSpMXQ PartitionCount: 2   ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs:
    Topic: orders   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2,1
    Topic: orders   Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
```

After killing VM2:

```
Topic: orders   TopicId: I3hMNln9TpSuo76xHSpMXQ PartitionCount: 2   ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs:
    Topic: orders   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2
    Topic: orders   Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2
```

After killing VM1:

```
Topic: orders   TopicId: I3hMNln9TpSuo76xHSpMXQ PartitionCount: 2   ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs:
    Topic: orders   Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 1
    Topic: orders   Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1
```

After killing VM2:

```
Topic: orders   TopicId: I3hMNln9TpSuo76xHSpMXQ PartitionCount: 2   ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs:
    Topic: orders   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2
    Topic: orders   Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2
```

(From here, the producer can't publish message anymore)

Comment: Your transaction topic only has one replica, by the way

Comment: Also, you're not mounting any volumes, right? So, how are you guaranteeing the data you're producing remains after killing the brokers? Specifically, there will be no topic directories inside the container, so check their logs to find errors about that

Comment: As you said my transaction topic only has one replica, i add "TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2" when i start brokers, but i have the same behavior. Maybe i misunderstood what you mean about that.

And about volumes, you're right. But for now, it's not important to me to retrieve data after killing brokers.

Comment: It's not strictly required, but I remember reading that transactions are enabled by default in latest Kafka versions

Comment: And the data is important. You shouldn't be able to produce to a topic while the broker is restarting and replicating data from other brokers to rebuild its `log.dirs`

Comment: But how you explain the everything work fine at the beginning ? When i kill VM2 and send a message, it's ok. Then i restart VM2 and kill VM1, i send a message and it's still ok, finally when i restart VM1 and kill VM2 i got the problem.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but if you kill and restart one VM, there's data available to replicate back from the other. If you kill the other that had all the data, then that data is now gone, and requires replication again from the other, which may not have completed.... Try using volumes and see if you get the same problems. Otherwise, look at the broker logs and see what's happening internally

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion. 
Unfortunately i tried with volume, i checked that the data is well persisted (it's ok !), but the problem is still the same :(
Any other idea ?

Comment: After step 11 here, can you show the output from describing the topic? I assume the leader is the correct broker and the ISR list is missing the down broker?

Comment: The answer is below.

Comment: That doesn't look like a solution to your problem, so you should edit the question. And like I said, you should look at the broker logs for any problems while you're producing

Comment: After investigating a long time... i have tried to call kafka-leader-election and i can see a log error : "Error completing leader election (PREFERRED) for partition: __consumer_offsets-48: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PreferredLeaderNotAvailableException: Failed to elect leader for partition __consumer_offsets-48 under strategy PreferredReplicaPartitionLeaderElectionStrategy". I think this is not normal and maybe the cause of my problems. But i can't find on the internet what this error really mean. Any idea ? Maybe the consumer_offsets topic is not replicated yet when i kill the broker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of reading and investigating things about kafka, i finally found the answer of my problem.

With only 2 broker, i need the following configuration

```
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_NUM_PARTITIONS=1
```

The problem was the default number of partitions for the offset topics. (it was 49 of 50 if i remember well).

Now with only one partition and 2 replicas, everything works well and i can start/stop/start/stop/.... my brokers as many time as i want, and the other broker take the lead and continue to handle my messages.

Hope that could help someone in the future.